# Function to remove all trailing whitespace

Tags: functions, whitespace

I have the following function to remove every trailing white space from the document, without changing my cursor position

```
function! StripTrailingWhitespaces()
  let l = line('.')
  let c = col('.')
  %s/\s\+$//e
  call cursor(l, c)
endfunction
```

I'd like to change it so that it doesn't remove any whitespace to the left of my current cursor position. For example consider this situation, (a `_` stands for a space and `|` is the cursor position)

```
test__|_
```

there's the string `test` followed by three spaces, and the cursor is between the second and the third space. If I execute that function, I end up with

```
test|
```

and all the spaces have been removed, instead I'd like to end up with

```
test__|
```

where only the space to the right of the current cursor position has been removed (all the other trailing whitespaces throughout the document should be removed in both cases, I only want to change the behaviour on the current line).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the zero-width `\%#` to match the cursor position, so something like

```
substitute/\%#\s\+$//e
```

on the current line, and your other pattern on the other lines:

```
global/\%#/substitute/\%#\s\+$//e
vglobal/\%#/substitute/\s\+$//e
```

Unfortunately, by the time either `:substitute` is happening, the cursor position has moved. So let's save it and make the matches more exact with `\%123l` and `\%123c` for matching exact lines and columns:

```
let [_, line, col, _, _] = getcurpos()
execute printf('global/\%%%dl/substitute/\%%%dc\s\+$//e', line, col)
execute printf('vglobal/\%%%dl/substitute/\s\+$//e', line)
```

But now that we already have the line number, we don't need the first `:global`:

```
let [_, line, col, _, _] = getcurpos()
execute printf('%d substitute/\%%%dc\s\+$//e', line, col)
execute printf('vglobal/\%%%dl/substitute/\s\+$//e', line)
```

Then you can surround it with `winsaveview()` and `winrestview()` to handle the cursor position.

PS technically the first substitute does not need the line number, but being explicit does not hurt.

Comment: *This* version actually worked in my testing

Comment: That moves the cursor to the end of the document, but even after adding a `call cursor(line, col)`, the cursor gets moved one space to the left with every save.

Comment: @noibe yeah I didn't address the part about restoring the cursor; I figured you had that figured out already. You could try passing `col+1` to the first printf and see if that helps? You may also be interested in `winsaveview()` and `winrestview()`

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a lot.

Comment: you don't need `%d substitute`. The `:s` command works on the current line per default, if no range is given. BTW: I second the use of `winsaveview()` and `winrestview()`, since even if the position might stay the same, the viewport could change. This does not happen with `winsaveview()`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt yeah i know about the first substitute; consider it defensive programming :) at the time i was struggling with global moving the cursor to the beginnings of lines and wanted to be absolutely explicit with my intentions.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble understood

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with several substitutions.

```
" bookmark current position
normal! m`
" remove whitespace on the current line
silent! keepj s/\%#\s\+$//
" same for lines above
silent! keepj 1,- s/\s\+$//
" same for lines below
silent! keepj ''+,$ s/\s\+$//
" restore cursor position
normal! g``
```

Comment: Hm, using relative ranges was clever. Nit: `:normal! m` is the same as `:mark` or `:k`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Not exactly. `:mark` as all Ex-commands is linewise, but we want to save also the column number.

Comment: doh! You’re correct.